# HAProxy not forwarding requests properly

Tags: reverse-proxy, system-administration, haproxy

I have this HAProxy config file:

```
frontend main
    bind *:80
    use_backend drewgrosscom if { hdr(host) -i drewgross.com }
    use_backend drewgrosscom if { hdr(host) -i www.drewgross.com }

backend drewgrosscom
    server app1 127.0.0.1:8000 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 1
```

But I'm getting "no data received" on both `drewgross.com` and `www.drewgross.com`. Accessing `www.drewgross.com:8000` and `drewgross.com:8000` both work fine though. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `mode http`.  This should work:

```
defaults
    mode http

frontend main
    bind *:80
    use_backend drewgrosscom if { hdr(host) -i drewgross.com }
    use_backend drewgrosscom if { hdr(host) -i www.drewgross.com }

backend drewgrosscom
    server app1 127.0.0.1:8000 check inter 5000 rise 1 fall 1
```